# Library or other means of producing labels (web based)

Tags: web-development, php, printing

I am looking for a means of producing printable custom labels (web-based). Data is supplied by a database. Preferably a PHP library or something that I can work with in PHP.

I've looked at FPDF and TCPDF already and not quite what I want. Just need something simple.

Any ideas?